# In php class object not working inside normal function?

Tags: php

```
<?php 
class Door
{
    public function __construct()
    {

    }
    public function test(){
        echo "welocme";
    }
}
$obj=new Door();

get_data();

function get_data(){

$obj->test();

}
```

$obj->test(); work well outside function but i need inside function. I cannot access object inside function show error

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function test()
```

Comment: if my ans is helpful for u, then accept my answer. And i have updated with some explanation..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try like this:**   it may work..

If u use any outer variable in a function, then decleare as `global $use_variable_name` . now u can understand...

```
function get_data(){
global $obj;
$obj->test();

}
```

**another and better way:**

```
get_data($obj);// call this way...
function get_data($object){
$object->test();

}
```

Comment: Thank you working well... but i don't know reason for not working

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? Please add an explanation of what you did and why you did it that way not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: I have doubt in this concept how to access object inside function....  In codeigniter i did $ci =& get_instance() to access object so that

Comment: @Rizier123 i'm facing real time problem this is not duplicate please remove duplicate

Comment: @user3743689 Tell me why *you* think this is not a dupe?

Comment: @Rizier123  my problem fixed use this answer

Comment: @user3743689 And you know what the problem was?

Comment: @Rizier123 Yes i know

Comment: @user3743689 To use `global` is **very** bad practice!  Pass the variable as argument to the function

Comment: @Rizier123 ok dude now i accept you ans now i'm expecting good one please remove duplicate

Comment: @user3743689 I won't put an answer in. In the duplicate it's very good explained why your code failed, what's the reason for it and how to solve the problem the *right* way, so that your code stays nice and clean

Comment: @Rizier123  Please explain my question to fail....   In your question that is explanation but this is real time problem so many difference there explanation and problem

Comment: @Rizier123 You people are always irritating others